# Overflow and Underflow in Java Float and Double Data Types

Tags: java, overflow, underflow

I have created the following code to test Float and Double Java numeric data types for underflow and overflow:

```
// Float Overflow & Underflow
float floatTest = Float.MAX_VALUE;
floatTest++;
out.println("Float Overflow: " + Float.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + floatTest);
floatTest = Float.MIN_VALUE;
floatTest--;
out.println("Float Underflow: " + Float.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + floatTest);
out.println("");

// Double Overflow & Underflow
double doubleTest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
doubleTest++;
out.println("Double Overflow: " + Double.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + doubleTest);
doubleTest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
doubleTest--;
out.println("Double Underflow: " + Double.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + doubleTest);
out.println("");
```

Can someone explain the weird values I see in the result:
[image]

When I do the similar test (code below) with byte, short, int and long:

```
// BYTE Overflow & Underflow
byte byteTest = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
byteTest++;
out.println("Byte Overflow: " + Byte.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + byteTest);
byteTest = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
byteTest--;
out.println("Byte Underflow: " + Byte.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + byteTest);
out.println("");

// SHORT Overflow & Underflow
short shortTest = Short.MAX_VALUE;
shortTest++;
out.println("Short Overflow: " + Short.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + shortTest);
shortTest = Short.MIN_VALUE;
shortTest--;
out.println("Short Underflow: " + Short.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + shortTest);
out.println("");

// INTEGER Overflow & Underflow
int intTest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
intTest++;
out.println("Integer Overflow: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + intTest);
intTest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
intTest--;
out.println("Integer Underflow: " + Integer.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + intTest);
out.println("");

// LONG Overflow & Underflow
long longTest = Long.MAX_VALUE;
longTest++;
out.println("Long Overflow: " + Long.MAX_VALUE + " + 1 = " + longTest);
longTest = Long.MIN_VALUE;
longTest--;
out.println("Long Underflow: " + Long.MIN_VALUE + " - 1 = " + longTest);
out.println("");
```

The results look as expected:

[image]

Can someone explain overflow and underflow in Java float and double and why am I seeing above results?

Comment: What you see are the correct range values for java primitive data types. https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_04.htm https://dzone.com/articles/overflow-and-underflow-data

Comment: Underflow isn't the same thing for floating types as it is for integer types.  With floating types, underflow means "we're so close to zero, that our value is likely to become insignificant and vanish entirely when we do arithmetic".  With integer types, underflow means "we're at the smallest possible integer, so we're in danger of wrapping around to the largest possible integer, when we do arithmetic".

Comment: ***REQUIRED READING***: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These "weird" results are not really specific to Java. It's just that floats as defined by the relevant IEEE standard, are much more complicated than most people suspect. But onto your specific results: `Float.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest **positive** float, so it's very close to 0. Hence `Float.MIN_VALUE - 1` will be very close to -1. But since the float precision around -1 is greater than that difference, it comes out as -1. As to `Float.MAX_VALUE`, the float precision around this value is much greater than 1 and adding one doesn't change the result.

Comment: Thanks,  @Andreas, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

## Floating Point Overflow

Adding `1` to `Double.MAX_VALUE` OR `Float.MAX_VALUE` doesn't represent enough of a value to avoid getting rounded down due to precision error.  At `Double.MAX_VALUE`, the [difference between consecutive values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-), due to there being 53 bits for mantissa, is quite large.

```
System.out.println("Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE) is " + Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE));

1.9958403095347198E292
```

This value is 2<sup>971</sup>.

You need to add an expression that yields at least this much to overflow to `Infinity`.  I say "yields at least this much" because I can get this to overflow by adding 2<sup>970</sup>, but 2<sup>969</sup> has no effect.

```
doubleTest += Math.pow(2.0, 969);

1.7976931348623157E308
```

And

```
doubleTest += Math.pow(2.0, 970);

Infinity
```

It looks like 2<sup>970</sup> gets rounded up to 2<sup>971</sup> to get added to `Double.MAX_VALUE`, but 2<sup>969</sup> gets rounded down to `0` and has no effect on the sum.

A similar process is occurring for `float`, though the values aren't nearly so high.

## Floating Point Underflow

```
doubleTest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
doubleTest--;
```

This is just an infinitesimal value minus one, which is practically minus one.  This not underflow.

Underflow occurs when the *exponent*, not the value, gets too low to be represented, so `0.0` results.  Divide by `2` instead to get underflow.

```
doubleTest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
doubleTest /= 2;

0.0
```

## Integer/Long Overflow/Underflow

Those are the expected values because you know the values "wrap around" to the other side of the range of values.

Answer (score 0):

your results aren't necessarily out of the ordinary, it's just that floats in general are very specific and your request is very close. I have had similar problems while using double data types. Just double check to make sure that your code checks out with what you were expecting.